# VLC and streaming via RTSP: wrong colors

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

I am getting a via streaming via rtsp from a videocamera located in my LAN. I am using VLC to get such stream.
VLC used to work correctly a few hours ago, but now it stopped behaving correctly and when I try to watch the stream, colors are messed up: it looks like I am catching some sort of negative of the images (even though it is not actually a negative).
When I open that stream from other players, it works correctly.

I tried to change the cache, but I am totally sure it is not a network load problem.
I am running everything on windows server 2008. On this same environment, it was working a few hours ago.
Do you have any clue what the problem can be? Where could the problem lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong settings on my client Apple terminal were configured: 16bit instead of 64. After changing that, when connecting remotely, everything worked out.